# What is the difference between an Android Activity and Service

Tags: android

Am having a great confusion between activity and service. My aim is to run a music player. In most of the document said, to run a background work for an activity you should use service. But its possible to invoke a player from a thread created by an activity itself. Moreover, the thread wont destroy  even if the activity destroyed.

If so, what is the usage of service here ?
Why should we use service and when to use service ?

Plz clarify my doubt !

Thanks in advance.

Comment: The thread may not end when the activity ends, but it will end when its process is killed, which could be at any time.

Answer (score 10):

Activity is a GUI and service is non-gui thread which can run in the background. Some more details [here.](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/fundamentals.html)

Comment: IntentService is running in background while service is running on GUI thread.